# Eliminate the variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am struggling with one key aspect of this eliminate the variable problem.
$x=\tan (t); y=\cot (t)$ and $ 0<t<\pi/2$

If I am graphing this in Q1 as indicated by the problem given boundary I clearly get the graph of $y=1/x$ since $\tan x$ is $1/\cot x$

But the text gives the correct answer as a hyperbola $y^2-x^2=1$ and they do this using the identity $\csc^2 t=\cot^2t +1$.  While I know this trig identity I do **not** see how this results in  $y^2-x^2=1$.

How would I get the more generalized equation in rectangular for $0<t\le2\pi $.  In other words, how would I get the hyperbola solution of this problem?  Or, ***IS*** there a hyperbola solution if the boundary restrictions are lifted?

Comment: The textbook is incorrect. It happens. (You're correct.)

Answer (score 1):

$$\cot(t)= \frac{1}{\tan(t)}$$ so $$xy= \cot(t)\tan(t)= \frac{\tan(t)}{\tan(t)}= 1$$